# HealthKit and Apple Watch - How to check if workout is running?

Tags: ios, swift, watchos-2, healthkit

I working on an app which uses workout sessions to request heart rate data with a high frequency. Everything works perfectly if I create a new workout session from the app. Unfortunately, there is a usability issue. If user activates a workout from another Watch OS app (let's say for jogging or something), then my app has to stop his workout first, before starting a new one. How do we check if there is another Workout session already going? What I want to achieve is basically to utilise a session which is already running.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to check whether a workout session is already running in another app.

Comment: Alian answer is correct, from another App it's not possible, BUT from the same app there is a HKWorkoutSessionDelegate which follows the states of workout so you can check this.